# Do different Christian denominations think each other will be saved?

Tags: soteriology, comparative-christianity, denomination

There're lots of Christian denominations out there. I'm wondering if each of them have an official answer to "if the Second Coming were today, believers of [other denomination] will/will not be saved". I'm interested in both the bigger denominations (Catholicism, Anglicanism, Methodism ...) and the smaller ones (Mormonism, Jehovah's Witnesses ...). A full list is likely impractical, but partial tables are also good.

I haven't been able to find anything about this except scattered statements [such as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah%27s_Witnesses) "[Jehovah's Witnesses] consider secular society to be morally corrupt and under the influence of Satan, and most limit their social interaction with non-Witnesses" which implies that this denomination will say answer the question with "no" for every other denomination. It's possible I am searching for the wrong terms though, so I am asking this question.

**Edit:** some clarifications per the comments. I'm only interested in the official doctrine, not the beliefs of individuals. A denomination thinks the other will be "saved" if members of the other denomination are treated the same as members of the original denomination at the Second Coming. It is "not saved" if they are treated the same as unbelievers (i.e. non-Christians). For everything else in between, it's "partial" (i.e. part yes, part no).

Related: [Do non-Christians go to hell?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75527/do-non-christians-go-to-hell), however this question is about people who also identify as Christian.

Comment: I hope whoever answers this question supplies a machine readable format that I can use for a graph algorithm to find the denomination least likely to go to Hell!

Comment: this is such a broad question, you might want to narrow it down to just one or two denominations

Comment: I think the general answer is that the Trinitarians generally consider each other to be truly saved, but not the non-Trinitarians, while the non-Trinitarians don't consider anyone other than those in their own theological camp to be saved (not necessarily only their own denomination, there are breakaway LDS denominations for example and they may consider each other saved.)

Comment: @curiousdannii the beginning of a overview style of answer?

Comment: VTC:NMF, traditionally questions like this were closed very quickly because they can only be efficiently answered from a single denominational or traditional perspective. The biggest problem is what does it mean to be "saved?" I assure you, there's a very different meaning between, e.g., Baptists, Catholics, and Mormons. And speaking from the LDS perspective it's very important to know what you mean because from one perspective we believe everyone is saved but those who follow the Devil and from another we believe only Latter-day Saints are saved. So, which perspective are you asking from?

Comment: @JBH "saved" here means that members of the other denomination ends up getting whatever members of the denomination get after the Second Coming. In other words, members of the denomination are not special relative to the other denomination. From your description, LDS also answers the question with "no" for every denomination except fellow LDS members.

Comment: It's more complex than that. We do not believe in a binary heaven/hell. We believe in three kingdoms of glory and one "perdition" or kingdom without glory. We believe that only members of the LDS faith can obtain the highest of the three kingdoms of glory, but that membership isn't a guarantee. There will likely be a fair share of LDS members in the other three kingdoms. Thus, what does it mean to be saved? As one forum member mentioned to me decades ago, "I won't be a Mormon, but I like them, because I get something in their religion anyway." (\*continued\*)

Comment: The reason I bring this up is because there are disparities between theologies about what it means to be "saved." It would almost be more practical to ask, "what does each theology believe concerning final judgement of members of other theologies?" but that question is inappropriate here because it generally can't be answered by a single respondent. Thus, the reason why the site usually (at least in the past) required questions like this to be asked from the perspective of a single tradition.

Comment: @JBH in that case, let's have "yes" if members of the other denomination are treated the same as believers, "no" if they are treated the same as unbelievers (i.e. non-Christians), and "partial" for everything in between.

Answer (score 2):

From a conservative Baptist perspective, which I no longer am but with which I am very familiar, the only people who are 'saved' are those who, in acknowledgement of their sin, have relinquished faith in any and every other thing including good works and religious activity and personally assign their entire hope to the sacrificial death of Christ for the atonement of their sin and to the resurrection of Christ for the imputation of Christ's righteousness to their account.

CB's believe that 'salvation' is an intensely personal and not a corporate affair and is not imparted by a creed or a baptism, nor conferred by a priest or any ritual.

CB's believe that this is what constitutes being 'born again' or 'born from above' and that it is a permanent translation from death to life.  CB's believe that sitting under accurate biblical teaching (especially about the person of Christ) certainly increases the likelihood that a person might respond (and most Baptist churches seem to believe that they teach the most accurately...or maybe that's just all churches) but that church attendance, bible reading, denominational adherence, sacramental participation, and theological training guarantee nothing.

In short, CB's believe that only those who are born again are actually Christian and are saved, regardless of denomination or self-designation.

Answer (score 1):

From the Seventh-day Adventist perspective, yes, people of other faiths will be saved. Jesus said clearly that he has his sheep in other folds.

It is wrong for any Bible believer to judge any other human, as we are expressly admonished not to. Judgement belongs to God, and it is not for us to include or exclude anyone. Any attempting to do so need to be very careful to rather point to the peril to which sin exposes you and to do so in as non-judgemental a fashion as possible. This can be rather difficult in practice, but it helps to think of all souls as infinitely valuable.

It is only in the light of eternity that the true value of a human soul can be appreciated.

I suspect most Protestant faiths hold this position as it is almost a defining point of Protestantism which rose against the Papal claim to hold the keys to heaven and that only through her could salvation be granted.

Comment: Thanks for answer. By "other faiths", are you referring to all faiths (so Buddhists, Hindus etc will also be saved), or just those of other Christian denominations?

Comment: Jesus did not define. We are not to judge either inclusively or exclusively to any man. Judgement as to who will or will not be in the kingdom is the exclusive domain of Jesus. The direct answer is to reiterate that it us not for any human to declare any faith excluded. Note that individuals will be saved, not faiths. It is a well known teaching of Adventists that being a SDA is not a guarantee of salvation. That extends across all humanity without borders or boundaries. Salvation is an intimately personal experience and issue.